# Calling javascript code contained in a variable

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have the below anchor tag

```
<a rel="2" onclick="javascript:aimsCCUAQuestionsBanner('TOPIC','VAC_FIOSTV_PROD_AVAIL','CPTU');" name="&amp;lid=choose_topic_fiostvchangeservice" id="opt1tv1" href="javascript:void(0);" class="tv-avail">Billing </a>
```

No whenever  "Billing" is clicked I have to call aimsCCUAQuestionsBanner('TOPIC','VAC_FIOSTV_PROD_AVAIL','CPTU'). Also when the user clicks on another hyperlink present on the same page, the onclick function has to be read and executed the same like how its called when "Billing" is clicked.

Im reading the onclick function using mootools into a variable like below

```
var func = $("step-1").getElement('a#'+step1_id).get('onclick');
```

But when Im trying to execute the function like below

```
  window[func]();
```

The function is not being called in both FF and IE. Can someone tell me how to execute the function from the variable?

Comment: can you just try      func()    ?

Comment: Its throwing error.."func is not a function". But when I try directly like this..var func = aimsCCUAQuestionsBanner('CHANGE_CATEGORY','VAC_MAIN', ''); func();..It wirked..But hardcoding wont work for me.I have to read the function value dynamically.

Comment: Look my update in the below comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do eval of the function

```js
eval(func);
```

Try http://jsfiddle.net/99MrC/1/ for example

Update::
What your trying to do is getting the attribute value of anchor tag which is "javascript:aimsCCUAQuestionsBanner('TOPIC','VAC_FIOSTV_PROD_AVAIL','CPTU');"
 This will be a string and not function. So you need to eval for browser to execute the string as javascript.

When you said this is working

```
var func = aimsCCUAQuestionsBanner('CHANGE_CATEGORY','VAC_MAIN', '');
func();
```

that is because when you executed

```
var func = aimsCCUAQuestionsBanner('CHANGE_CATEGORY','VAC_MAIN', '');
```

it already executed the function.

The next call

```
func();
```

supposed to fail because it is not function, unless your function returns another function

Comment: It is apparently my code is working in IE9 too. May be also remove "javascript:" from onclick. But still it should work. I dont know how your code is not working. help me with more code so that I debug it

Comment: I could see in many sites that it is not advisable to use eval..using eval will open yourself to XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yes it does. I hope that is what you want. But there is not much of a porblem in your case. The best practice is to have a function and that function as a handler to both hyperlinks on load of the document.